# how to upload and save qif file using php

Tags: php, codeigniter, file, codeigniter-3

I am trying to upload a .qif file in php codeigniter but it returns an error

> The filetype you are attempting to upload is not allowed.

When I try to upload another type file (PDF, CSV, docs, etc.) they upload successfully.

Here is my code:

```
function do_upload($field_name, $files, $folder_path,$save_name="",$prefix="bk_"){
    $ci =   & get_instance();
    //create upload folder if not exists
    if (!is_dir($folder_path)) {
        mkdir($folder_path, 0777, TRUE);
    }
    $save_name =   $prefix.time()."_".$files['name'];
    $data                       =   array();
    $config                     =   array();
    $config['upload_path']      =   $folder_path;
    //$config['max_size']         =   0;

    $config['allowed_types'] = 'csv|CSV|txt|TXT|pdf|PDF|zip|ZIP|doc|DOC|docx|DOCX|xlsx|xls|XLS|XLSX|QIF|qif';
    $config['file_name']    =   $save_name;
    $ci->load->library('upload');
    $ci->upload->initialize($config);
//    echo "hello 1"; die;
    if ($ci->upload->do_upload($field_name)){
        $data           =   $ci->upload->data();
        $data['status']    =   1;
    }
    else{
        $data['status']    =   0;
        $data['error']  =   $ci->upload->display_errors();
    }
    return $data;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You get the "filetype is not allowed" error, because the original Codeigniter mime-type configuration file doesn't list an qif entry:

in your `config/mimes.php` file add to the `$mimes` array this line:

```
'qif'   =>  'application/qif'
```

and eventually

```
'qif'   =>  'image/x-quicktime'
```

mime-type source: http://fileformats.archiveteam.org/wiki/Ext:qif

the native php [move_uploaded_file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php) method without checking for mime-types can turn into a security problem

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution after  lot of searches
I just use move_uploaded_file function and it's work

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $path);
```

if someone have a better answer answer please share that.

thanks